# Cannot restore database because of stuck rollback

Tags: sql-server, restore

When I try to restore my database with

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDatabase
FROM DISK = '\path\to\my\backup.bak'
WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY
```

It says

> Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.

After some googling I tried this instead:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
RESTORE DATABASE MyDatabase
FROM DISK = '\path\to\my\backup.bak'
WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY
GO
```

However, this seemed to take forever and when I eventually cancelled the command it told me that

> Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 0%.

The message repeated multiple times and the progress was always 0%.

I'm not a DBA --sadly my company does not employ any-- and I have no clue where to go from here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can restart the SQL Server service, then:

- Stop the SQL Server service
- Delete the old data/log files for MyDatabase
- Start the SQL Server service again
- At that point, you can delete the (offline) database
- Do your restore